# Send keyboard and mouse events to DirectX application in C#?

Tags: c#, directx, mouseevent, sendkeys, sendinput

I need to send global keystrokes and mouse events to another application, which is coincidentally using using DirectX. (No controls/handles other than the window itself)
For example, I need to hold key X for 2 seconds and then release it...
I need to push Right Click down on coordinates x:600 and y:350, move the mouse 100 pixels down and then release the Right Click.
I also need to push 2 or more keys at once, like X and Y, and stop X after 2 seconds and Y after 2 more seconds.
So basically I would need full control of the input system...
It would also be ideal if I could control the application while maximized or in background. (optionally)

For the skeptics... The teacher made a DirectX application for drawing for our school. I am asked to make an application that draws samples on it, like a train or flower or something... I will be reading images and use the input to set the color and click on the canvas...

Comment: Sounds like game bot programming ;-)

Comment: Drawing application for kids. School project!

Comment: To be honest, your post diverges from the original question and becomes rather broad.

Comment: @DanielB It's okay. It indeed sounds like bot programming. @Mr. Disappointment What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities. You may have a look at `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` and you can pInvoke some Win32 functions like `SetForegroundWindow()`, `LockSetForegroundWindow()` from gdi32.dll or from user32.dll `SetCursorPos()` and `mouse_event` to perform clicks:

Here a snippet for the Mouse events I used a while ago.

```
    /**
     * Mouse functions
     */
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern long mouse_event(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dx, Int32 dy, Int32 cButtons, Int32 dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern void SetCursorPos(Int32 x, Int32 y); 

    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    public const Int32 MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;

    public static void PerformLeftKlick(Int32 x, Int32 y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Hope that pushes you in the right direction. A good resource is http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: @DanielB But how do I send key X pressed and key X released after a while?

Comment: Thats a question I have no answer for. Maybe by pinvoking also.

Comment: Mouse or Keyboard? DX window is in foreground?

Comment: It's okay but can you help me find the right way of doing this? :C

Comment: Did you send KEYDOWN and after a while KEYUP? maybe this post could help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/d5d6097e-f221-452e-8b65-5659e2c9faaa/

Comment: Not even the sample PressKey does anything.

Comment: :( Sounds strange, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have an idea: Administrator rights are required to send key events... That is SO retarded!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a library for C# that will make your work easier then read following link -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate

Other than .Net C# you can use other language alternative like in Java where, there is no confusion of direct x or normal input -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Hi Vercas, It is for a new search person which can help him/her greatly because we all are experienced to answer for the query  :)

Comment: I've been digging into this problem and I've found that library works great except that it's using SendInput (User32.dll function).  Unfortunately, that doesn't work for DirectX games that use DirectInput.  I'm still looking for a solution for this, but I suspect it will involve writing a keyboard driver.

Comment: @Richard If you can use Java or wrapper for Java Program to avoid Direct X Input issue, you can use Robot class as suggested. Or any similar solution (Which I am not sure which is similar to Robot) will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, Java is not my skillset.  Instead, I installed the Interception keyboard driver and hooked into that.  It saved me from writing one myself.  Using that, it's sending as if it were from a keyboard.  The only downfall is when I debug, I can't use my normal hotkeys for stepping into and such, because the keyboard interface is tied up due to the debugger.  But it works well.